How should I use Spring Beans inside a Scala Object?
I have Scala code that looks something like
@Component
class A (@Autowired val componentB: B) {Something}

@Component
class B (@Autowired val beanC: C) {Something}

@Component
class D () { 
  @Value("${configProperty}")
  val configProperty = ""

  @Bean
  def foobar: C = {Something}
}

@SpringBootApplication
class MainClass extends ApplicationRunner {
  def main(): Unit = {
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[MainClass]
  }
  override def run(): Unit = {Do nothing}
}

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Component
object SparkRunnable extends MainClass {
  override def run(): Unit = {
    val annotationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(classOf[SparkRunnable])
    val wiredClass = annotationContext.getBean(classOf[A])
  }
}

When I try running the code defined above I get
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'A': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'B' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I need SparkRunnable to be an object because it needs to run in Spark.
I can see that all the beans and component classes are being set up correctly from debugging and logs, but I just can't seem to be able to get the beans in a way where I can use them inside the SparkRunnable object.
I tried wiring the beans manually, like below, but it does not even have context to fetch the properties configured in the yaml files.
val uselessWiringVal = annotationContext.getBean(classOf[D])
val uselessWiringObj = new B(uselessWiringVal.foobar)
val wiredClass = new A(uselessWiringObj)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'A' defined in URL[SparkRunnable]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'D': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'configProperty' in value "${configProperty}"

I'm a beginner in Scala and probably made a mistake trying to use SpringBoot for this kind of job. My questions are,

Is there something wrong in the way I'm setting up my component classes?
How do I actually fetch the components to use from my RunnableObject?

Being able to do something like
object SparkRunnable (@Autowired A) extends MainClass {}
would be ideal, but that syntax does not work.
I can get the autowired component in the class SparkRunnable but I can't find a way to pass it to the companion object either.

While this is not what you're asking, I think you're gonna have plenty of issues trying to use Spring with Spark. Is there any strong reason for wanting to use Spring?

@GaëlJ The Spark app hits a couple of APIs does some business logic before moving on the heavy Spark stuff. Thought Spring might make the API part a bit cleaner, turns out I created a bit of mess.
